# No More Import Button on Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I no longer see the import button on Parse to import a JSON or CSV file. Did they move it somewhere or is it no longer possible to import those file types?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: There is no code to display. Parse used to have an import button that allowed you to drag and drop CSV and JSON files to create a new Class. It seems as though they have removed the button and I cannot find any other way to make this happen. I want to know if there is another way to do it or not.

Comment: No. I think that button is gone for good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the official reason is this:

"[The import class button] was removed a couple of days ago due to an app that was abusing it and affecting people that had not migrated out yet. Now that the database is running on your own infra, you can simply importing directly to mongo so this shouldn’t be blocking you."

I hope this helps (to answer the question, not to import your class of course).

Cheers,

Comment: That really sucks but Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where did you find this official reason?

Comment: its really sucks. I want to migrate my app to mongo but i have to backup my database, so i cloned my app but it didn't cloned my objects and contents so how can i backup ?

Comment: Hey @JakeT. Hector Ramos from Parse/Facebook replied an email I sent to him.  Those words between the quotes are his.